# How to detect collision using PyBox2d and use that information

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, box2d

I am trying to filter collisions occurring in my Box2D world by reproducing this example: https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/blob/master/examples/collision_filtering.py

I have four classes in my world, Car, Wheel, Building, and Pedestrian, I want to filter which instance collided with which and one of the possible outputs is (pseudo-code)

```py
if contact.FixtureA.isinstance(Pedestrian) and contact.FixtureB.isinstance(Car):
    print("You have caused a traffic accident")
```

I have this set of categories

```py
CAR_CATEGORY = 2
PEDESTRIAN_CATEGORY = 4
BUILDING_CATEGORY = 8
box2world = world(gravity =(0.0, 0.0), doSleep =True)
```

I also tried this: but it doesn't work (it does nothing)

```py
class myContactListener(b2ContactListener):
    def __init__(self):
        b2ContactListener.__init__(self)
    def BeginContact(self, contact):
        fixture_a = contact.fixtureA
        fixture_b = contact.fixtureB

        body_a, body_b = fixture_a.body, fixture_b.body
        ud_a, ud_b = body_a.userData, body_b.userData
        pedestrian = None
        car = None
        for ud in (body_a, body_b):
            if isinstance(ud, Pedestrian):
                pedestrian = ud
            elif isinstance(ud, Car):
                car = ud

        if car is not None and pedestrian is not None:
            if began:
                print("It does stuff")
            else:
                print("It does something")
    def EndContact(self, contact):
        pass
    def PreSolve(self, contact, oldManifold):
        pass
    def PostSolve(self, contact, impulse):
        pass


box2world = world(contactListener=myContactListener(),gravity =(0.0, 0.0), doSleep =True)
```

and I apply this in given classes (only class Pedestrian shown as example for simplicity):

```py
class Pedestrian():
    def __init__(self,box2world, ped_velocity =25, position =None,):

        if position == None:
            position = [5,5]
        self.ped_velocity = ped_velocity
        self.position = position
        self.box2world = box2world
        self.nearest_building = 0
        self.body = self.box2world.CreateDynamicBody(position = position, 
                                                       angle = 0.0,
                                                       fixtures = b2FixtureDef(
                                                            shape = b2CircleShape(radius = 1),
                                                            density = 2,
                                                            friction = 0.3,
                                                            filter = b2Filter(
                                                                categoryBits=PEDESTRIAN_CATEGORY,
                                                                maskBits=BUILDING_CATEGORY + CAR_CATEGORY,
                                                                groupIndex=0,
                                                                    )))
        self.current_position = [self.body.position]
        self.body.userData = {'obj': self}
```

And then I draw the bodies and run the world using pygame

But I am confused about how to continue, how could I use the information from the collisionfilter to be able to for example print the sentence about the accident from above?

Thank you very much
EDIT: I have found a link which solves exactly what I want to do, but it is written in C++ and I do not understand it
http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks

Comment: Could you try with the box close to but not exactly 45 degrees?  If the physics engine is simple enough having the box land at exactly 45 degrees will have it in unstable equilibrium and so it will stay there until moved even a tiny amount.  If 46 degrees falls one way and 44 the other, then you probably have this unstable equilibrium case.

Comment: Ok, that"s interesting and it helped, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your second comment that is more complex so I add it as another answer.

You don't handle collisions yourself, Box2D does it for you but you need to set things up.

**- create your world**

```
world = b2.World.new(0, 24, true)
```

**- attach listeners to your world (for collisions handling)**

```
world:addEventListener(Event.BEGIN_CONTACT, self.onBeginContact, self)
world:addEventListener(Event.END_CONTACT, self.onEndContact, self)
world:addEventListener(Event.PRE_SOLVE, self.onPreSolveContact, self)
world:addEventListener(Event.POST_SOLVE, self.onPostSolveContact, self)
```

**- in your game loop you need to call Box2D update**

```
self.world:step(1/60, 1, 1)
```

**- then *ANSWER IS HERE* you check collisions for each objects in those box2d functions listeners**

```
-- collisions handler
function LF_Bullet:onBeginContact(e)
    local bodyA = e.fixtureA:getBody()
    local bodyB = e.fixtureB:getBody()
    if bodyA.type == 100 or bodyB.type == 100 then
        self.removebullet = true
    end
    if bodyA.type == 200 and bodyB.type == 100 then
        bodyA.isdead = true
    end
    if bodyA.type == 100 and bodyB.type == 200 then
        bodyB.isdead = true
    end
    if bodyA.type == 201 and bodyB.type == 100 then
        bodyA.isdead = true
    end
    if bodyA.type == 100 and bodyB.type == 201 then
        bodyB.isdead = true
    end
end

function LF_Bullet:onPreSolveContact(e)
end

function LF_Bullet:onPostSolveContact(e)
end

function LF_Bullet:onEndContact(e)
end
```

This is a quick example written in LUA using **gideros mobile** http://giderosmobile.com/.

**A must website regarding box2d is of course:
https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/**

It is a vast subject and you may want to follow some youtube tuts. Even if it is not written in py, box2d works the same so you just have to adapt to py.
Some links that may help:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZm85UZQLd2SXQzsF-a0-pPF6IWDDdrXt

That's how I learned using box2d. Hope that helps?

Comment: Thank you, with your help I was able to filter collisions and now when a pedestrian hits my car I can print("Accidents happen") Enjoy +100 Reputation and again, thank you very Much :)

Comment: But unfortunately another problem occured, I do not want to ask a new question for this so I will try to find out how to fix it this way, maybe you will be able to help me, please see edit for details

Comment: @Mechatrnk could you please open another question, it think that's how stackoverflow works. Maybe someone else or I could get some points. Thank you for the +100 :-)

Comment: @Mechatrnk at first sight it seems you didn't check car and building collisions. Try adding another if like so: if car_contact is not None and building_contact is not None: ... ?

Comment: Nope, that does not help, OK I will ask a new question (I thought that it would be some kind of spamming... )

Answer (score 2):

hey I just answered your question on stackexchange :-)

For collisions it's easy:

```
local filterData = {
   categoryBits = player,
   maskBits = wall + nme + platform,
   groupIndex = 0
}
fixture:setFilterData(filterData)
```

**player**, **wall**, **nme**, ... are integers variables (must be power of 2 numbers):

```
player = 1
wall = 2
nme = 4
... = 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, ...
```

**categoryBits** = main object you want to test collisions on

**maskBits** = you **add** (with +) all the numbers the main object can collide with.

It's better to store the numbers as variables otherwise it would look like:

```
local filterData = {
   categoryBits = 1,
   maskBits = 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 ...,
   groupIndex = 0
}
fixture:setFilterData(filterData)
```

:-)

Comment: Thank you, I thought about your code a bit and it makes sense (sorry for commenting after more than a month) but I have still one question, what is groupIndex? :)

Comment: And maybe a more important question, how can I use the filtered data to for example this (pseudo-code) If CollisionBodyA == Car and CollisionBodyB == Pedestrian: print("Oops, an accident happened)? :)

Comment: groupIndex are like layers, so fixtures inside the same layer collide (or not) with each others. If the layer has a negative index (ex: -3) then all fixtures inside this layer will not collide with each others. See this link for more info http://box2d.org/manual.pdf