# PyBox2D - NoneType is not subscriptable during collision filtering

Tags: python, box2d, collision, nonetype

I have a Box2D world where I need to filter collision I have three entities there, a Car, a Pedestrian and a Building. Details can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710804/how-to-detect-collision-using-pybox2d-and-use-that-information) where I was told to ask a new question. I finally managed to filter the collision, when a car hits a pedestrian it does something, but when the car hits building I get an error that *"NoneType is not subscriptable"* how can I fix it? Thank you

```py
CAR_CATEGORY = 0x0002
PEDESTRIAN_CATEGORY = 0x0004
BUILDING_CATEGORY = 0x0008

CAR_GROUP = 2
PEDESTRIAN_GROUP = -4 
BUILDING_GROUP = 8

class myContactListener(b2ContactListener):
    def handle_contact(self, contact, began):
        # A contact happened -- see if a wheel hit a
        # ground area
        fixture_a = contact.fixtureA
        fixture_b = contact.fixtureB

        body_a, body_b = fixture_a.body, fixture_b.body
        ud_a, ud_b = body_a.userData, body_b.userData


        pedestrian_contact = None
        car_contact = None
        building_contact = None
        for ud in (ud_a, ud_b):
            obj = ud['obj']          
            if isinstance(obj, Car):
                car_contact = obj
            elif isinstance(obj, Pedestrian):
                pedestrian_contact = obj
            elif isinstance(obj, Building):
                building_contact = obj

        if car_contact is not None and pedestrian_contact is not None:
            if began:
                print("Shame on you, you killed an innocent pedestrian!!!")

        elif car_contact is not None and building_contact is not None:
            if began:
                print("BOOMMM")
    def __init__(self):
        b2ContactListener.__init__(self)
    def BeginContact(self, contact):
        self.handle_contact(contact, True)
    def EndContact(self, contact):
        pass
    def PreSolve(self, contact, oldManifold):
        pass
    def PostSolve(self, contact, impulse):
        pass

box2world = world(contactListener=myContactListener(),gravity =(0.0, 0.0), doSleep =True)
```

How can I fix the error?
Any help appreciated

Comment: The error message sounds like you may need to check the `ud` for `None` before doing `ud['obj']`, e.g. like so: `if ud is None:    continue` (continue on next line, indented).

Comment: Thnk you, this helped and probably solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code has only one *subscription* (one use of `[]` brackets), the error message means you may need to check the `ud` object for `None` before doing `ud['obj']`, like so:

```
if ud is None:
    continue
```

The same error message can be triggered in any python interpreter like so:

```
>>> a = None[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

The official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html?highlight=subscript#grammar-token-subscription) defines subscriptions:

> 6.3.2. Subscriptions
>
> A subscription selects an item of a sequence (string, tuple or list)
>   or mapping (dictionary) object:
>
> subscription ::=  primary "[" expression_list "]"
>
> The primary must evaluate to an object that supports subscription
>   (lists or dictionaries for example). User-defined objects can support
>   subscription by defining a **getitem**() method.

... and goes on to define the built-in types of objects that do support subscription.